# Import of Excel File with Small Row Height (row/cell records found in the wrong place)

Tags: grails, apache-poi, grails-plugin

I'm using "Excel Import & Export (Apache POI)" plugin in grails for importing my Excel data into my system. If I proceed the export, I receive following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: row/cell records found in the wrong place
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java:162)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:305)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$create.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.plugins.excelimport.AbstractExcelImporter.read(AbstractExcelImporter.groovy:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I see that the error comes from Apache-poi but I don't know how to deal with it in my application. The error disappears if I open the excel file and set row height to any reasonable size (i.e. 0.18"). The previous height was 0.02".

Is this a bug of Apache-poi or can I handle it somehow?

Comment: How was the file originally generated? And what version of POI are you using?

Comment: I can't say because the data come from my customer; but I'm pretty sure that they were exported by another system maybe that's why the row hight is set to such stupid size... The version of POI comes from Grails Plugin. I think they're using POI 3.7

Comment: I'd suggest you try running the [Microsoft Binary File Format Validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeinteroperability/archive/2011/07/12/microsoft-office-binary-file-format-validator-is-now-available.aspx) against the source file, and check it's actually a valid xls file.

Comment: Hm, nice:-) Files are invalid, so I'll ask my data provider to provide me valid data or I can also open the file and re-save it which fix the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Binary File Format Validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeinteroperability/archive/2011/07/12/microsoft-office-binary-file-format-validator-is-now-available.aspx) my file was invalid. Opening the file with MS Excel and re-saving it resolved this problem.